# Problem with Authlogic and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, authlogic, rspec-rails

I'm writing a simple Survey application using Authlogic gem. When I did testing using rails built in test tools everything worked well but now with Rspec I'm getting following error : This error is coming when it tries to run the command `require "authlogic/testcase" from spec_helper.rb`

```
/home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- authlogic/testcase (LoadError)
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
from /home/gunanka/survey/spec/spec_helper.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/gunanka/survey/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `map'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /home/gunanka/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:11:in `block in autorun'
```

It is trying to fetch authlogic/testcase from activesupport/dependencies instead of authlogic. Please can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong.
Versions:
ruby -1.9.2
rails - 3.0.10
authlogic - 3.0.3
rspec -2.6.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Once again silly mistake , it should be "require authlogic/test_case" !!! I entered "require authlogic/testcase" :)